# How to properly sequence and react to actions in RxJS and redux-observable?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm still learning the ropes as far as RxJS goes. I'm using `redux-observable` in my project and I am really enjoying it. However, I feel that I'm failing to grasp some fundamentals here so I'd like to ask for your help.

Here's the sample code:

```js
const requestDelete = action$ => {
  const actionSuccess$ = action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.AN_ACTION_THAT_MAY_FAIL_SUCCESS),
    take(1),
    mergeMap(_ => of(actions.deleteSuccess()))
  )

  const actionFailed$ = action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.AN_ACTION_THAT_MAY_FAIL_FAILED),
    take(1),
    mergeMap(_ => of(actions.deleteFailed()))
  )

  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.REQUEST_DELETE),
    mergeMap(action =>
      from(SomeService.delete(action.payload)).pipe(
        mergeMap(_ =>
          merge(
            actionSuccess$,
            actionFailed$,
            of(actions.requestAnActionThatMayFail())
          )
        ),
        catchError(err => of(actions.deleteFailed(err)))
      )
    ),
    catchError(err =>
      of({ type: 'CRITICAL_REQUEST_DELETE_ERROR', err })
    )
  )
}
```

This is the flow that I have in mind:

1. User requests delete of some resource.
2. A `SomeService` is called to do that.
3. If it resolves, I would like to call `requestAnActionThatMayFail`. Now, I would like to depend on the result of that action and wait for it to finish.
4. If it is ok, I would like to go with `actions.deleteSuccess())`.
5. If it fails, I would like to trigger errors etc. with `actions.deleteFailed()`.

Now, the thing is - this code *works*, but the `merge` feels bad to me. I thought that I should use `concat` and put the `of(actions.requestAnActionThatMayFail())` as the first argument. If I change the order of streams or use `concat`, the whole epic won't work. Any ideas what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I change the order of streams

I would suspect it won't work this way because `requestAnActionThatMayFail` is a **synchronous action**. This explains why, because `merge` will subscribe to the provided observables **sequentially**, meaning that if you have

```js
merge(
 actionFailed$,
 of(actions.requestAnActionThatMayFail()),
 actionSuccess$,
)
```

and `requestAnActionThatMayFail` is successful, it won't work because `actionSuccess$` has not been subscribed yet(`actionFailed$` is subscribed). If `requestAnActionThatMayFail` was **asynchronous**, you shouldn't encounter this issue.

> or use concat

`concat` is `merge` with `concurrent` set to 1. While `merge` can have multiple active inner observables, `concat` can have only one. When having `concurrent` set, `merge` will buffer the exceeded values and when one inner observable **completes**, it will take the oldest buffered value and will create an inner observable out of it.
The explanation is the same as the one in the previous section: the other observables **are not** subscribed yet.

So, here would be my approach:

```js
const requestDelete = action$ => {
  const actionSuccess$ = action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.AN_ACTION_THAT_MAY_FAIL_SUCCESS),
    take(1),
    mergeMap(_ => of(actions.deleteSuccess()))
  )

  const actionFailed$ = action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.AN_ACTION_THAT_MAY_FAIL_FAILED),
    take(1),
    mergeMap(_ => of(actions.deleteFailed()))
  )

  const requestDelete$ = action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.REQUEST_DELETE),
    mergeMap(action =>
      from(SomeService.delete(action.payload)),
      mergeMap(_ => of(actions.requestAnActionThatMayFail())),
      catchError(err => of(actions.deleteFailed(err)))
    ),

    // This seems a little redundant because of the previous `catchError`
    // catchError(err =>
    //   of({ type: 'CRITICAL_REQUEST_DELETE_ERROR', err })
    // )
  )

  // Make sure all the obs. are susbcribed
  return merge(actionSuccess$, actionFailed$, requestDelete$);
}
```

Comment: I am thankful for the elaborate answer. I thought that streams are treated equal, regardless of the synchronicity (i.e. that it is somehow normalized "under the hood"). Again, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful!